# Correct way of using Using with inner using

Tags: c#, .net, using

I am downloading some XML string from a URL and I need to parse it. So, I have the following syntax:

```
// Code Section 1    
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    response = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(myUrl));
}

SyndicationFeed myFeed;
using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(response)))
{
    myFeed= SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
}

if(myFeed != null)
{
    // Do something
}
```

But, a teammate has raised a concern that code will look better if I do

```
// Code Section 2
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    string response = await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(myUrl));

    using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(response)))
    {
        SyndicationFeed myFeed= SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
        if(myFeed != null)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }   
}
```

Logically, they perform the same task, perhaps there might be some performance impact.

My questions are:

- What is the correct way of using `using` with an inner `using`?
- Should I "release" the memory as soon as possible, which means put as fewer logic as possible inside the `using`?

Comment: You could wrap each using in a separate method that returns the response/feed  and then just call each of them, if you are going for readability (i tend to use this approach)

Comment: I think it is better to call dispose on an object as soon as nobody use it again. So the first approach sounds like a better one to me.

Comment: If after you get response from webClient, you don't need webClient anymore then I would say your original code is better. Why hold on to the instance of webClient if you don't need it anymore. Same as dotctor, he just types faster.

Comment: Both codings are fine, i prefer the second as its more readable and compact.

Comment: The first is the more "correct". It releases the resources faster, but it's no big deal really, if it were written in the second form.

Comment: Why don't you post this on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and see what you get there?

Comment: @roryap, wow, I didn't know that there is a code review section, it must be new

Comment: @FelixCen -- Sure, it's about 6 years old.  Is that new?

Comment: hahah, never heard about it, I must be in a cave all the time

Answer (score 3):

> What is the correct way of using using with an inner using?

Well, you don't have an *inner* `using` here. Your two `using` blocks are completely independent.

If you *had* two dependent `using` blocks (for example database connection and recordset), your second approach would be mandatory.

Right now, it's a matter of style. Strictly speaking, the first approach is a bit better because it's disposing resources earlier, but in this case, it really does not matter. Pick the one you like best.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, the example under (1) ensures a better separation of concerns. As a practical example, it's easier to decompose such code into separate methods. The logical coupling between each `using` statement is lower, and there is no implied nesting of scopes that enforces a *reverse* order

On the other hand, the code under example (2) will lead to a longer life-time of the outer resource. In practice, it *may* and *may not* have a significant impact on performance and resource consumption.

As a rule of thumb, I would prefer option (1) as it is less coupled, allows better resource management, separates concerns, and is easier to refactor.

Note: As nvoigt correctly points out in his answer, the applicability of (1) over (2) in your specific situation is possible thanks to the fact the resources *are not* dependent on each other.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to call dispose on an object as soon as nobody use it again. So the first approach sounds like a better one to me.
I will also extract the logic in two separate method.

```
public static async string GetWebData(string url)
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        return await webClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(url));
    }
}

public static async SyndicationFeed ProcessWebData(string data)
{
    using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(response)))
    {
        return SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
    }
}
```

and then the code will be like

```
var response = await GetWebData(myUrl);
var myFeed = await ProcessWebData(response);
if (myFeed != null)
{
    // Do something
}
```